# Creating a rectangle with css and a 'triangle edge'

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a container with css that has a rectangle header with a 'triangle edge'.

Example:

[chrome example](http://jsfiddle.net/BNVHU/3/)

Or code here (css):

```
.bubble {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 350px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);  
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 90; /* the stack order: displayed under ribbon rectangle (100) */
}

div#container {
    margin: 50px auto 0px auto; /* centered */
    padding-top:100px;
    width: 400px;
}

.triangle {
   height: 35px;
   top: -20px;
   width: 315px;
   position: relative;
   background: #D12738;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 39, 56, 1) 0%, rgba(122, 23, 38, 1)    100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(209, 39, 56, 1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(122, 23, 38, 1)));
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d12738',  endColorstr='#7a1726',GradientType=0 ), filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
}

.triangle::after {
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
   content: "";
   height: 44px;
   left: 302px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 2px;
   width: 24px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="bubble">
        <div class="triangle">test baa</div>
        <p>sadsadsadsad dsdsa dsdsa ds dsadsd</p>
        <p>sadsadsadsad dsdsa dsdsa ds dsadsd</p>
        <p>sadsadsadsad dsdsa dsdsa ds dsadsd</p>
        <p>sadsadsadsad dsdsa dsdsa ds dsadsd</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

But the border on the right edge dissapears because of the white background. Is there any way to prevent this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't accomplish what you're trying to do by creating a triangle with that method, because by definition you're blocking out a piece of the rectangle with something that's also going to block out whatever else is behind it.

The way to accomplish what you want to accomplish is to create a triangle using a border. Here's a link and a fiddle to how you might accomplish this:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/
http://jsfiddle.net/BNVHU/7/

Unfortunately, border gradients only work with webkit at this time, and don't seem to jibe with the border method of making triangles. I doubt that there's a way to do this with a gradient intact in all browsers. Might need an image.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Too bad about the border gradients. I will fix it with an image for now then.